# Como crear Backup de base de datos mysql con c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Lo que quiero es con un simple click en una opción aparezca una ventana para guardar el respaldo de la base de datos.

Un cuadro de dialogo en el que se pueda guardar en cualquier lado el Backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Llama a `mysqldump` en el `oclick` con el nombre de la base datos. Para ello necesitas tener instalado `mysqldump` en el cliente y tener en el path la ruta de instalación de `mysqldump`.

```
strCmdText= "mysqldump.exe --databases mydatabase -uroot -padmin --result-file=file.sql";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

Comment: me explicas mejor lo de mysqldump ?

Comment: Lo que estarias haciendo seria invocar un programa externo desde tu aplicacion. mysqdump es el programa externo. lo puedes adquirir al instalar mysql. puedes ejecutar mysqldump con los parametros que te convengan y obtener el resultado en algun directorio cliente. revisa la documentacin de mysqldump para mas informacion: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html